# Consider the graph G. What is the distance of the vertex 8 from the vertex 7

Tags: graph

[image]

From the graph. It seems 7 will never reach 8 because of the direction arrow. Will the distance of 8 from 7 be the infinity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance is gonna be infinity since 7 can never go to 8